# How to edit the "not enough stock" or "not enough stock already in cart" message in WooCommerce 4.5+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

On my Woocommerce shop, when I try to add a larger quantity of an item to my basket than we have in stock (i.e 10 if we have 9) I get this message...

[image: error message]

I wish to change that to say something along the lines of 'Out of stock, please contact our sales office'

Does anyone know what code I can drop into my `functions.php` that will achieve this?

I tried this code snippet and strangely, if I add 9 items to my basket, then try to add another 1, I can get the correct message to appear...

```php
add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_add_to_cart_stock_error_notice', 10, 3 );
function custom_add_to_cart_stock_error_notice( $translated, $text, $domain ) {

if ( $text === 'You cannot add that amount to the cart &mdash; we have %1$s in stock and you already have %2$s in your cart.' && 'woocommerce' === $domain ) {
    $translated = __("You are currently trying to order more of this product than are currently available at your shipping location. Please call our sales team to discuss availability", $domain );
}

return $translated;
}
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have tried your code and it works for me. I am displaying the custom message correctly. Have you tried clearing the cache? Have you tried increasing the priority of the hook filter? Do you necessarily have to use custom code or can you also install a translation plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/translation/

Answer (score 2):

**Note: there is a difference between**

- You cannot add that amount of ... to the cart because there is not enough stock (... remaining)
- You cannot add that amount to the cart — we have ... in stock and you already have ... in your cart

They are shown separately from each other even though they are similar

---

The way since WooCommerce **4.5.0** to edit the **"not enough stock"** message is to use `woocommerce_cart_product_not_enough_stock_message` filter hook.

```php
/**
 * Filters message about product not having enough stock.
 *
 * @since 4.5.0
 * @param string     $message Message.
 * @param WC_Product $product_data Product data.
 * @param int        $stock_quantity Quantity remaining.
 */
function filter_woocommerce_cart_product_not_enough_stock_message( $message, $product_data, $stock_quantity ) {
    // New message
    $message = __( 'You are currently trying to order more of this product than are currently available at your shipping location. Please call our sales team to discuss availability', 'woocommerce' );
    
    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_product_not_enough_stock_message', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_product_not_enough_stock_message', 10, 3 );
```

---

---

The way since WooCommerce **5.3.0** to edit the **"not enough stock already in cart"** message is to use `woocommerce_cart_product_not_enough_stock_already_in_cart_message` filter hook.

```php
/**
 * Filters message about product not having enough stock accounting for what's already in the cart.
 *
 * @param string $message Message.
 * @param WC_Product $product_data Product data.
 * @param int $stock_quantity Quantity remaining.
 * @param int $stock_quantity_in_cart
 *
 * @since 5.3.0
 */
function filter_woocommerce_cart_product_not_enough_stock_already_in_cart_message( $message, $product_data, $stock_quantity, $stock_quantity_in_cart ) {
    // New message
    $message = __( 'You are currently trying to order more of this product than are currently available at your shipping location. Please call our sales team to discuss availability', 'woocommerce' );
    
    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_product_not_enough_stock_already_in_cart_message', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_product_not_enough_stock_already_in_cart_message', 10, 4 );
```